# compiling golang using intellij is looking for wrong path of 3rd party packages

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I'm using IntelliJ with the go plugin to write my application.

version of Go: `go version go1.7beta2 darwin/amd64`

Operation system: `OSX El Capitan 10.11.5`

Intellij Version: `2016.1.3`

Go Installation Location: `/usr/local/go`

Go Pkg Location ($GOPATH): `/Users/ufk/projects/go`

when I open terminal, browse to my application's main source file, and type `go` it compiles it properly without any errors.

but when I try to Run the program using Intellij, which also compiles it, i get the following error:

```
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: cannot open file /usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/codegangsta/negroni.a: open /usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/codegangsta/negroni.a: no such file or directory
```

lookgs like it's looking for the negroni package in the location when I have go installed, and not where I the 3rd party packages are installed according to `$GOPATH`. My project is configured to use $GOPATH, and the real time error of the intellj editor doesn't complain about packages that are not installed which means that Intellij does check the $GOPATH variable.

so what am i missing ?

thanks

## update

Hi :)

I noticed something new... I have 2 go projects, one of them is the JSON Api Server, and the other is for the web server.
The project that is causing issues is the Api Server.
now, the web server also uses and imports negroni, but the problem occurs only on the Api Server Project.

so I decided to go wild and delete the .idea and iml file from the Api Server, reopen it with intellij, and see what happens... welp, what happens is that now it complains about a different module.

```
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: cannot open file /usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jingweno/negroni-gorelic.a: open /usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jingweno/negroni-gorelic.a: no such file or directory
```

the thing is.. that my web server project also uses negroni-gorelic and things are fine!

I tried downgrading go from 1.7beta2 to 1.6.2, deleting the content of the modules ($GOPATH/pkg and in src directory github.com and golang.org)
then I got all the modules again.. tried to compile with intellij and the results are the same.

so... hope this helps to further investigate the issue.

Comment: This looks like the GOPATH is not configured in the plugin. Can you check that you've added it in: File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Go | Go Libraries and add the GOPATH (and only the GOPATH there). If you have any issues, please ping me on Gitter and I'll help you out.

Comment: @dlsniper. hi! thanks for your input. I'm on gitter now, and i don't know on what room to search for you (couldn't find a way to search for specific people). anyhow updated main post.  hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I've totally missed this, please join us here: https://gitter.im/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin Ping me with @dlsniper when you are around. Thanks!